# Ionic 3, <ion-list>, how to make the top item aligned to the top?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In short, I want to achieve something similar to the iOS' date dial, but simpler: no round surface effect and border image, just plain text items only and only three items visible.

I think I could start with `ion-list`. I would just need to make the list height to be of 3 * the item height, and when scrolling stops, the top should be aligned with the first item, preferably with rubber-band animation. Since there already is such an over-scroll animation at the end of the list, the component should already have such animation in it.

If what I mean is not clear, please see the image below.
[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0dks.png]

Comment: then is it mandatory to use this for  ?  and did you see that Select https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

Comment: No, not a drop-down list. I want something I can put on the page, not a popup item. That iOS picker is a popup, but that was just to help to explain how it works. I do not want that popup thing.